# Using a db connection inside foreachRDD in apache spark streaming

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, spark-streaming

In spark streaming, I want to query the db before each batch is processed, store the results in a hashmap that can be serialized and sent over a network to the executors.

```
class ExecutingClass implements Serializable {
 init(DB db) {

   try(JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(...)) {

   JavaPairInputDStream<String,String> kafkaStream = getKafkaStream(jsc);

   kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
   // this part is supposed to execute in the driver
  Map<String, String> indexMap = db.getIndexMap();// connects to a db, queries the results as a map

  JavaRDD<String> results = processRDD(rdd, indexMap);

  ...  

 }


  }
    JavaRDD<String> processRDD(JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd,       Map<String,String> indexMap) {
 ... 
    }
    }
```

In the above code, the indexMap is supposed to be initialized at the driver, the resulting map is used in processing the rdd. I have no problems when I declare indexMap outside of foreachRDD closure but I am getting serialization errors when I do it inside. what is the reason for this?

The reason I want to do something like this is to ensure I have the latest values from the database for each batch. I suspect this is due to the closure of foreachRDD trying to serialize everything outside the closure.

Comment: why cant use accumulator(read write)/ broadcast (readonly) for this purpose?  In this case since it is read write accumulator makes sense isnt it ?

Comment: Code inside the closure will be serialized and sent to the executors. So I would assume `db.getIndexMap()` is not serializable for this purpose.

Comment: @LiMuBei That's the catch. For each batch of data, we first query the database to get the indexMap, and then pass over only the indexMap for processing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **db** object ( which is instance of DB), inside forEachRdd so spark tries to serialize **db** , for avoiding this we need to create DB connection inside forEachRdd (or) you can make use of object pools as discussed in the below article 
http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/10/01/kafka-spark-streaming-integration-example-tutorial/